# How To Set Nav Bar Item Title From plist's index row?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sdk

My data is sourced in a plist and displayed in a tableview with navigation bar.

I want to load the subview with the cell that was clicked.

I know this would set it correct, but I'm not sure how to implement indexPath in the viewDidLoad method?

```
    self.navigationItem.title = [[self.exerciseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey: @"name"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       You have an array of Dictionary With you. Now IndexPath is seen called in TableView delegate methods. I doesn't mean that you can't create one. Create an NSIndexpath obect and assign the indexes parameters and send it to the function which contains the above code( separate the code which sets the title from the Cell for row at index path).
```

But the problem is as I see, You want to show only a specific set of data in dictionary  which is stored in an Array. The real problem is You should know which the index of the Array you want to load. to the title and the tableview. If you can know that then its solved.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Regards ,
Jackson Sunny Rodrigues

Comment: This is the plist I am using, the value I want for this specific table's title is the name value, such as "abdominal". http://www.box.net/shared/static/iag6j5q1ie.png

Comment: So you have to just know which item you are Showing. Inside it you have array of values for table and Name. So just fetch it from dictionary as Value for key and use it.